Logistic regression for win probability: parameterization
I am modeling the outcome of baseball games using a logistic regression. I am struggling to understand the results of the analysis, and I believe this relates to the parameterization of the model. Specifically, I observe asymmetric prediction accuracy, and I am trying to induce symmetry in the accuracy.
Suppose we have a set of covariates for the home team $\mathbf{x}_h$ and another for the away team $\mathbf{x}_a$. The first model I can think of sets $y = 1(\text{Home team wins})$, and lets
$$
y \sim f(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathbf{x}_1 + \beta_2 \mathbf{x}_2), \quad \mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{x}_h, \enspace \mathbf{x}_2 = \mathbf{x}_a
$$
This is a model where the home team is encoded as the first positional vector, and the away team as the second vector.
To analyze the performance of the model, I considered the conditional accuracy at different thresholds of the predicted probability $\hat{p} = P(y=1)$. Let $\hat{y} = 1(\hat{p})>0.5$. For a given threshold $\tau$, denote by $n_\tau$ the number of values of $\hat{p}_i$ greater than $\tau$ - ie, $n_\tau = \sum_i 1(\hat{p}_i > \tau)$. Then, I calculate the accuracy $\alpha_\tau = (1/n_\tau) \sum_i 1(\hat{y}_i = y_i | \hat{p}_i > \tau)$. I did this for values of $\tau > 0.5$; I also did this for $\tau < 0.5$ with the conditional $\hat{p}_i < \tau$.
Empirically, the model exhibits some bias:
   side   thr  accuracy     n
6     < 0.300     0.727    11
7     < 0.350     0.562    48
8     < 0.400     0.545   165
9     < 0.450     0.531   426
10    > 0.500     0.553  1404
11    > 0.550     0.578   948
12    > 0.600     0.630   506
13    > 0.650     0.684   215
14    > 0.700     0.793    58
15    > 0.750     0.733    15
16    > 0.800     0.667     3

As an example, the accuracy for predicting $y=1$ is 63% when $\hat{p} > 0.6$; but the accuracy for predicting $y=0$ is 55% when $\hat{p} < 0.4$. Maybe this makes sense: we weight towards home wins. But it is undesirable in a model, because the accuracy is not symmetric for the two teams.
So I did an exercise: randomize which team is home or away. This is equivalent to the above model, but $\mathbf{x}_1$ can be either $\mathbf{x}_h$ or $\mathbf{x}_a$ at random. This will remove any home-team advantage from the model, but I was curious to see what happened.
Results were similar when I considered the data with $\mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{x}_h$ for all out-of-sample evaluations:
   side   thr  accuracy     n
5     < 0.250     0.000     1
6     < 0.300     0.500     2
7     < 0.350     0.528    36
8     < 0.400     0.543   186
9     < 0.450     0.539   575
10    > 0.500     0.586  1060
11    > 0.550     0.618   471
12    > 0.600     0.722   144
13    > 0.650     0.818    22
14    > 0.700     0.833     6
15    > 0.750     1.000     3
16    > 0.800     1.000     1

But if I randomized the out-of-sample, as well, the accuracy paths are (finally) symmetric:

   side   thr  accuracy     n
5     < 0.250     1.000     1
6     < 0.300     1.000     2
7     < 0.350     0.655    29
8     < 0.400     0.617   175
9     < 0.450     0.586   539
10    > 0.500     0.547  1124
11    > 0.550     0.566   505
12    > 0.600     0.641   156
13    > 0.650     0.704    27
14    > 0.700     0.833     6
15    > 0.750     0.667     3
16    > 0.800     1.000     1

I noticed that in the asymmetric version, there are $n_{0.55}=471$ predictions above $\tau=0.55$, whereas there are 331 predictions that are either $<0.4$ or $>0.5$.
I am concerned that the parameterization with $\mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{x}_h$ is causing asymmetry in the prediction accuracy, and I would like to induce symmetry. How to interpret these results? Are there other ways to induce symmetry?
